# Is it possible to pass the ServiceProvider into a constructor parameter?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, .net-5

**Problem:**

We have a .NET 5 WPF application that has an EntityFramework Core entities class file `DbEntities`, which implements the `DbContext`. We use constructor injection when instantiating it. One of the options that we use is `AddInterceptors` in order to append an Access Token to the `SqlConnection`. The interceptor is called `AzureAuthenticationInterceptor`. When registering the service, we would like to pass in the `ServiceProvider` so that it is available in the interceptors constructor, which can be used to get a service that implements Access Token in-memory caching.

The reason for it is that we have a project with 50+ classes that all use the same `DbEntities` file, which takes 0 arguments in the constructor. This was upgraded to .NET 5 where Dependency Injection was avoided due to the work it would take to apply it to all of the forms. So, the `DbEntities` is instantiated in the forms with `new DbEntities();`.

But, in this case, we are implementing an access token cache, which needs to be registered as a service. Otherwise, if we just instantiate the cache every time we create a new `DbContext`, then the cache will be wiped out.

The access token in-memory cache is implemented using this method https://mderriey.com/2020/09/12/resolve-ef-core-interceptors-with-dependency-injection/

We only want to use dependency injection for the in-memory token cache. The only way we think of as a shortcut is to pass the `ServiceProvider` in the interceptor's constructor, but it does not appear available in the `ConfigureServices` method.

**Question:**

Is it possible to pass in the `ServiceProvider`? If not, is there any other way we can implement dependency injection on the interceptor without having to change 50 class files?

**Program.cs**

```
Public static void Main()
{
...
    Host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
        {
            builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            Configuration = context.Configuration;
            ConfigureServices(Configuration, services);
        })
        .Build();
...
}

private static void ConfigureServices(IConfiguration objConfiguration, IServiceCollection objServices)
{
    objServices.AddMemoryCache()
        .AddSingleton<IAzureSqlTokenProvider, AzureIdentityAzureSqlTokenProvider>()
        .Decorate<IAzureSqlTokenProvider, CacheAzureSqlTokenProvider>()
        .AddSingleton(new AzureAuthenticationInterceptor(IServiceProvider_NeededHere))
        ;
}
```

**DbEntities.cs**

```
public DbEntities() :
base(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbEntities>()
    .UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbEntities"].ConnectionString)
    .AddInterceptors(new AzureAuthenticationInterceptor())
    .Options)
{ }
```

**AzureAuthenticationInterceptor.cs**

```
public AzureAuthenticationInterceptor(IServiceProvider objServiceProvider)
{
    this.IAzureSqlTokenProvider = (IAzureSqlTokenProvider)objServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IAzureSqlTokenProvider));
}
```

Comment: Using: ```[...].AddSingleton(sp => new AzureAuthenticationInterceptor(sp))``` instead or simpler  ```[...].AddSingleton<AzureAuthenticationInterceptor>()``` but all of these depend on you implementation of ```AzureAuthenticationInterceptor``` and the constructors parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, avoid injecting `IServiceProvider`, it is a code smell and leads to poor design.

Refactor AzureAuthenticationInterceptor.cs

```
public AzureAuthenticationInterceptor(IAzureSqlTokenProvider tokenProvider) {
    this.IAzureSqlTokenProvider = tokenProvider;
}
```

So that way explicit dependencies can be injected as needed

```
//...

.AddSingleton<AzureAuthenticationInterceptor>()

//...
```

When resolving the interceptor while configuring the DbEntities

```
//...

services.AddDbContext<DbEntities>((provider, options) => {
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("<connection-string-name>"));
    options.AddInterceptors(provider.GetRequiredService<AzureAuthenticationInterceptor>());
});

//...
```

Note that if you are manually initializing the context using the default constructor, ie:`new DbEntities();` Then this bypasses the opportunity to apply dependency injection via constructor injection.

Comment: I agree that passing the ServiceProvider is a code smell. But, your solution seems incomplete. In your 3rd code block, it appears that you are attempting to implement dependency injection for the `DbContext`, which is what we want to avoid because that would require changing the 50 classes. In the `DbEntities.cs` file, an error is thrown that there is no constructor for `AzureAuthenticationInterceptor` that takes 0 arguments.

Comment: Per your edit, you are saying that it is not possible to implement dependency injection for the in-memory Access Token management system only because we are initializing the context using the default constructor. Am I correct?

Comment: @JWeezy That is correct. if you are manually initializing the class with the default constructor then there is no where to inject the dependency as part of the options needed for initialization.

Comment: Are there any other viable alternatives to cache the Access Token? Or, do we have to implement DI?

Comment: @JWeezy You could probably need to use a  static class like a sort of singleton but I am not too fond of that approach.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your help.